# Appending Data within another file

Tags: javascript, php

I am hacking a couple of Wordpress plugins together (Not that it matters).  I have an onclick function that relates to a `js` function that is located in another 'plugin' folder.

What would be the best way to link the main js file from location 1 into where I need it in location 2?

**Example:**

`onclick="call_ajax_add_to_quotelist(add_to_quotelist_ajax_url,'.$product->id.');" '.$style.'>'.$label.''`

`call_ajax_add_to_quotelist` is located in `wp-content/plugins/plugin1/js.js`

Comment: You should clarify your question before you get down-voted (*and that's a guaranteed thing here*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to load wp-content/plugins/plugin1/js.js when you need to use call_ajax_add_to_quotelist function:

```
<script src="...wp-content/plugins/plugin1/js.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps!